# Parse cron expression in NCronTab C#

Tags: c#, cron

I am using [NCrontab](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncrontab/) generator in C#. And I want to parse expression which will be start every first Monday , or every third Wednesday, or every second Sunday etc.
I find some expression [like this](http://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?Language=en-US&DayOfWeekStartIndexOne=false&Use24HourFormat=false&VerboseDescription=false&Expression=*%20*%20*%20*%20MON%233). But it doesn`t work in NCrontab.

Can you help me with this expression?

Comment: I solved this problem using [NCrontab Advanced](https://github.com/jcoutch/NCrontab-Advanced)
It parse expression like:0 0 * * MON#3

Answer (score 3):

In NCrontab you can use "0 0 1-7 * MON" for first Monday of month, "0 0 8-14 * MON" for second and so on.